# Register event handler for dynamically added selectInput

Tags: r, shiny

I'm currently working on a web application built with R Shiny which bases its functionality on dynamically created UI, including rendering additional input fields, namely `selectInput`. The `inputId` attributes of `selectInputs` are also created dynamically and I can't predefine the number of created `selectInputs` as it also varies based on the user's input.

The problem occurs when I want to react to the user changing the selected value in a dynamically created `selectInput`. Normally, if the `selectInput` was "static", I would register it with observeEvent:

```r
observeEvent(input$select_inputId, { ... })
```

However, I'm not able to preemptively register events for unknown number of not-yet-specified `inputIds`. Is there any possibility of passing some kind of event handler to `selectInput` or some other solution to this problem?

Here is the essential part of the code creating dynamically my UI:

```
observeEvent(input$rate_criterion_select, {
  output$rate_criterions_ratios <- renderUI({
    container <- tags$div()
    for(i in seq(1, length(children_criterions))) {
      container <- tagAppendChild(container, selectInput(
        inputId = paste(input$rate_criterion_select, i)
        label = ""
        choices = rates
      )
    }

    return(container)
  })
})
```

---

**EDIT:** Below you can find a reproducible example of the Shiny App. The solution would be to store values provided by user in commented `choices` variable. For instance: if user selected 3 inputs to fill and selected accordingly "One", "Two" and "Three", `choices` should be a vector `c("One","Two","Three")`; if user selected 2 inputs to fill and selected "Two", "Two" - `choices` should just be `c("Two","Two")`.

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)

# choices <- 

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$how_many, {
    output$render_area <- renderUI({
      container <- tags$div()
      for(i in seq(1, as.numeric(input$how_many))) {
        container <- tagAppendChild(container, selectInput(
          inputId = paste("selection", i),
          label = paste("Selection", i),
          choices = c("One", "Two", "Three"),
          selected = "One"
        ))
      }

      return(container)
    })
  })

})
```

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Example App"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
       selectInput("how_many", "How many inputs do you want to fill?", c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
    ),

    mainPanel(
       uiOutput("render_area")
    )
  )
))
```

Comment: Please post a reproducible example - code for a full app that others can run

Comment: I've just added code for a full example app that I hope shows clearly what is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer to your question, but I can see a few weird things in your code that should not be done. Here is a rewrite of your code that I suggest you use as your starting point:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Example App"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("how_many", "How many inputs do you want to fill?", 1, 1, 5)
    ),

    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("render_area")
    )
  )
)

server <-function(input, output) {

  output$render_area <- renderUI({
    lapply(seq(input$how_many), function(i) {
      selectInput(
        inputId = paste("selection", i),
        label = paste("Selection", i),
        choices = c("One", "Two", "Three")
      )
    })
  })

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

- Instead of a select dropdown that has numbers and then having to cast them to integers, just use a `numericInput()`
- You can create and return multiple select dropdowns using `lapplt()`, instead of using a for loop and `tagAppendChild()` - that's overkill
- You shouldn't define your `output$render_area` inside of an observer for `input$how_many`. The `output$render_area` should be top-level. I suggest reading some resources on reactivity because this code implies a misunderstanding of reactivity (it's a difficult topic!)

Again, this does not answer your question, but I hope it helps in all your future shiny code.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections, indeed I'm relatively new to Shiny and R overall and I got to know reactivity only on very basic examples.