# Remove button on each element dynamically added to a shiny UI

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to create a shiny app with a dynamic UI that adds an arbitrary number of input fields, adding one each time an action button is clicked. Once created these new inputs should be removable by clicking another action button that is added with the input, rather than for example selecting which element to remove from a list, as in this question [Register event handler for dynamically added selectInput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43530902/).

I worked from two examples in shiny's dynamic UI article: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html specifically: https://gallery.shinyapps.io/insertUI/ and https://gallery.shinyapps.io/111-insert-ui/ I don't like the way the first example requires that you pick which UI element to remove then click to remove it i'm looking to acomplish that with one click by adding a remove button to each new element.

Based on this stack overflow question I wrote the code below to make a reactive function that would listen to several inputs: [How to listen for more than one event expression within a Shiny eventReactive handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34731975/), Apparently however you cannot slice the input object: [Getting multiple checkbox values in Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16654697/), nor could I figure out how to get my reactive function determine out which remove button had been clicked so I think this approach is a dead-end. I'm new to shiny and reactive programming so I don't know all the features that well I would appreciate any suggestions for something that I can use to accomplish this result.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(

            actionButton('addBtn', 'Add input Set'),

            tags$div(id='inputList')
        ),
        mainPanel()
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    observeEvent(input$addBtn, {
        n <- input$addBtn
        id <- paste0("input",n)
        insertUI(
            selector = '#inputList',
            ui=div(
                selectizeInput(
                    inputId = id,
                    choices = c("Stuff","to","input"),
                    selected = c("Stuff"),
                    label = "An Input:",
                    multiple = TRUE
                ),
                actionButton(paste0('removeBtn',n), 'Remove')
            )
        )
    })

    # removeModelReact <- reactive({input[grepl(pattern = "removeBtn",names(input))]},{
    #   # which button changed... and return that
    # })
    # 
    # eventReactive(removeModelReact(),{
    #   removeUI(
    #       selector = paste0('div:has(> #input',removeModelReact(),')')
    #   )
    # })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi this should do it.

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$addBtn, {
    nr <- input$addBtn
    id <- paste0("input",input$addBtn)
    insertUI(
      selector = '#inputList',
      ui=div(
        id = paste0("newInput",nr),
        selectizeInput(
          inputId = id,
          choices = c("Stuff","to","input"),
          selected = c("Stuff"),
          label = "An Input:",
          multiple = TRUE
        ),
        actionButton(paste0('removeBtn',nr), 'Remove')
      )
    )
    observeEvent(input[[paste0('removeBtn',nr)]],{
      shiny::removeUI(
        selector = paste0("#newInput",nr)
      )
    })
  })
```

you were almost there, I just added an observer that would listen to the remove button just added an remove the UI. I also added an id to the div in the insertUI just to make it simpler later on to remove it.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks @beril-barton I would not have thought of placing the second `observeEvent()` inside the first obviating the need to keep track of the button identifier outside the scope of the first observer. I didn't know you could nest reactive expressions like that.

Comment: Many thanks for this approach - I was having a headache of how to dynamically add / remove user inputs.. `insertUI()`/`removeUI()` with a selector works like a charm!